# How to install run sql on windows mobile

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile

how to i transfer and install a database ( sdf ) on a windows mobile 6 pda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theere is no "install" of the file - it's just a single  file.  Copy it to the device via ActiveSync/WMDC or some storage mechanism.

*Ssing* the file requires the consuming application have the [SQL Compact binaries](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact-downloads.aspx) installed.  Microsoft also supplies a simplistic on-device query analyzer, which IIRC comes with the redistributables.

If you need something else, you need to be a bit more clear in your question.

**EDIT**

Once you install the redistributables on your PC, the various CAB files and binaries for SQL Compact will be stored here:

`%PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5`

Comment: Would link a link to the .cab files

Comment: K i think i found them, there are like 8, i will install all ok thanks